# How to store the data I get back from Postgres stored function

Tags: java, hsqldb

I am currently calling a stored function like the following:

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(my_function())
```

this function returns a table :

```
 RETURNS TABLE(
        userid            BIGINT,
        user_height    DOUBLE PRECISION
    )
```

How do i grab the two columns and store them into 2 array lists?

I Tried:

```
List<Object[]> data= query.list();
        List<Long> result= newArrayList();

        for (Object[] each: data)
        {
            Long userId= (Long) point[0];
            result.add(userId);

        }
```

I got the `exception: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: user lacks privilege or object not found: MY_FUNCTION()`

Answer (score 0):

`CALL` your stored procedure and map the results to a class of objects, as in this example:

```
class UserHeight
{
  public long userid;
  public double user_height;
}

Query query = session.createSQLQuery("CALL my_function()")
    .addEntity(UserHeight.class);

List result = query.list();
for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++){
    UserHeight height = (UserHeight)result.get(i);
    System.out.println(height.height);
}
```

Comment: Hi gknicker, I tried this but got an Unknown entity error. I created the class with those 2 fields. Tagged it with @ Entity and @ Table and created a table in the database.